# Handle inside an interpolation

Tags: css, sass, shopify, liquid, handle

Im building a store in shopify and Im fairly new at this.

I want to interpolate a collection.handle inside an interpolation, like this:

```
style="color: {{ settings.tomas_{{collection.handle}} }} !important;"
```

this is in order to create a dry formula to modify the css for every collection. Ive created my page colors in settings with this pattern:

tomas_example_collection: "FFF",
tomas_second: "F1F1F1"

And they work if I hard code them, but I dont know how to interpolate inside an interpolation.

What would you recommend?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass liquid inside liquid.

You need to generate the target string outside before passing it.

In your case:

```
{%- assign target = 'tomas_' | append: collection.handle -%}

style="color: {{ settings[target] }} !important;"
```

We create a variable that will hold the string and pass it using square brackets to the settings object.